# C++ Im trying to stream a file, and replace the first letter of every line streamed. It doesn't seem to be working as expected

Tags: c++, stream, fstream, ostream, istream

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>

void add1(std::fstream& files)
{

    char c;
    int i=0;
    int j=0;
    int k=0;
    int con=0;
    string word;

    while(files.get(c)&&!files.eof())
    {
        i++;
        j++;
        if(c=='\n'||(con>=1&&isspace(c)))
        {
            con++;
            if(con>=2)
            {
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<j<<"\/"<<i<<endl;
                files.seekp(i-j,files.beg);
                files.write("h",1);
                files.seekg(i);
```

`*`seekg ends the loops I tried fstream::clear. I think it would work perfect if seekg worked.

`+` without seekg it works but only for 3 lines then its off.

```
                j=0;
                word="";
            }

        }
        else
        {
            con=0;
            word=word+c;

        }
    }
}
```

---

`*`The goal is to be able stream the file, and replace the first letter of every line in the file while streaming.`*`

---

Comment: I just can't seem to be able to read and write at the same time with precision.

Answer (score 0):

You seam to have a logical error and make thinks overcomplicated.

I do not knwow, what you want to do with your variable "word". It is consumed nowhere. So, I will ignore it.

Then you are playing with read and write pointers. That is not necessary. You only need to manipulate the write pointer.

Then, you want to "stream" something. This I do not fully understand. Maybe it means, that you want to write always something to the stream, even, if you do not replace anything. This would in my understanding only make sense, if you would have 2 streams. But in that case it would be brutally simple and no further thinking necessary.

If we use the same stream and do not want to replace a character, then this is already there, existing, and maybe not overwritten by the same character again.

So, if there is nothing to replace, then we will write nothing . . .

Also, and that is very important, we do no replacement operation, if we have an empty line, because then there is nothing to replace. There is now first character in an empty line.

And, most important, we cannot **add** characters to the same fstream. In that case we would have to shift the rest of the file one to the right. Therefore. 2 streams are always better. Then, this problem would not occur.

So, what's the logic.

---

Algorithm:

We always look at the previuosly read character. If that was a '\n' and the current character is not, then we are now in a new line and can replace the first character.

That is all.

---

It will take also into account, if a '\n' is encoded with 2 characters (for example \r\n). It will always work.

And, it is easy to implement. 10 lines of code.

Please see:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

constexpr char ReplacementCharacter{ 'h' };

void replaceFirstCharacterOfLine(std::fstream& fileStream) {

    // Here we stor the previously read character. In the beginning, a file always starts
    // with a newline. Therefore we pretend that the last read character is a newline
    char previouslyReadCharacter{'\n'};

    // Here we store the current read character
    char currentCharacter{};

    // Get characters from file as lon as there are characters, so, until eof
    while (fileStream.get(currentCharacter)) {

        // No check, if a new line has started. We ignore empty lines!
        if ((previouslyReadCharacter == '\n') && (currentCharacter != '\n')) {

            // So last charcter was a newline and this is different. So, we are in a new, none empty line
            // Set replacement character
            currentCharacter = ReplacementCharacter;

            // Go one back with the write pointer
            fileStream.seekp(-1, std::ios_base::cur);
            // Write (an with taht increment file pointer again)
            fileStream.put(currentCharacter);
            // Write to file
            fileStream.flush();
        }
        else {
            // Do not replace the first charcater. So nothing to be done here
        }
        // Now, set the previouslyReadCharacter to the just read currentCharacter
        previouslyReadCharacter = currentCharacter;
    }
}

int main() {
    const std::string filename{"r:\\replace.txt"};

    // Open file
    std::fstream fileStream{ filename };

    // Check, if file could be opened
    if (fileStream)
        replaceFirstCharacterOfLine(fileStream);
    else
        std::cerr << "\n\n*** Error: Could not open file '" << filename << "'\n\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It's close. Though the replaced letters arent at the begging of every line. I think it has something to do with the innacuary of streams. I've been reading people use byte streams instead.

Comment: No, it works perfectly fine. As said, in empty lines, we cannot replace the first character, because there is none. This cannot work. If you want this to happen, you must use 2 streams, so a separate output stream. There is no inaccuracy of streams. The behaviour is well defined.

Comment: There's no empty lines. There's 'h's in the same line.